# Expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR for column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert a JSON string into a snowflake table defined below:

```py
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import VARIANT

class Identify(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'identify'

    event_id = Column(Integer, Sequence('event_id_seq'), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    traits = Column(VARIANT, nullable=False)
```

The `json_str` that I'm trying to insert is:

```
json_str = '''
{
    "address": "xyz",
    "age": 32,
    "avatar": "xyz",
    "birthday": {
      "seconds": 20,
      "nanos": 10
     }
}
'''
```

I'm using the following code to insert the `json_str` into the table

```py
session = Session()
obj = Identify(user_id=request.user_id,
               traits=json_str)
session.add(obj)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Which yields the following error: `snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 002023 (22000): SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(3038) for column TRAITS`

**Is there a way to insert the `json_str` or a `dict` without writing an SQL insert statement that uses the `TO_VARIANT` conversion function?**

Answer (score 0):

Is that valid JSON?   Looks to me like you have unmatched brackets...

-Paul-

Comment: Thanks - updated the bracketing in the question.  Was a copy-paste issue.

Answer (score 0):

The API doc says VARIANT is supported for ***fetching data*** by converting to a string.
I've found no other way to ***store data*** than an `INSERT` converting STRING to VARIANT.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the language in the API doc and thought it was odd that there is no ORM method.